# Bizzare output from substr

Tags: perl, substring, cgi

I am trying to extract year from a code which looks like **cs600032016s**. 
The year lies from index 7 to 10 but just to generalize on the variable length of the code preceding it, I have used the following code:

```
$year = substr($code, $len-5, $len-1);
```

But it gives me `2016s` rather than 2016. Any idea where the mistake is? Changing `$len-1` to `$len-2` or `$len-3` gives no change to output. It's very weird. 
This is the code:

```
sub getCCodeFromCode{
  my ($code) = @_;
  my $len = length($code);
  return substr($code, 0 , $len-5);    #4 char for year and one for sem
}

sub getYearFromCode{
  my ($code) = @_;
  my $len = length($code);
#  print "substr($code, $len-5, $len-1)";
  return substr($code, $len-5, $len-1);
}

sub getSemFromCode{
  my ($code) = @_;
  my $len = length($code);
  return substr($code, $len-1);
}

my %hashmap = &getCourseList;
#my %hashmap = %{$hashmap_ref};

foreach my $key (keys %hashmap) {
  my $code = &getCCodeFromCode($key);
  my $year = &getYearFromCode($key);
  my $sem = &getSemFromCode($key);
  print $key."\n".$code."\n".$year."\n".$sem."\n";
  #print "<p>$key = $hashmap{$key}<br>qq$code b $year b $semqq</p><br>\n";
}
```

This is the output:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Add Assignment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
cs600172015a
cs60017
2015a
a
cs410012015a
cs41001
2015a
a
cs220012016a
cs22001
2016a
a
cs600442016a
cs60044
2016a
a
cs300022015a
cs30002
2015a
a
cs600032016s
cs60003
2016s
s
cs500022015a
cs50002
2015a
a
cs220012016s
cs22001
2016s
s

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Calling subroutines with an ampersand `&` hasn't been correct since Perl 4.0 twenty-three years ago. So `&getCourseList` should be `getCourseList()`. Whichever tutorial you're using you should get a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation for `substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) says this

> substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH
>
> Extracts a substring out of EXPR and returns it. First character is at offset zero. If OFFSET is negative, starts that far back from the end of the string. If LENGTH is omitted, returns everything through the end of the string. If LENGTH is negative, leaves that many characters off the end of the string.

So the third parameter is the *length* of the substring you want to extract, not the offset of the end

However, you could use negative numbers for the start and end, which will be indices from the end of the string. Like this

```
$ perl -E"say substr 'cs600032016s', -5, -1"
```

#### output

```
2016
```

Comment: @sudeepdino008: That's not a comment that will endear you to the majority of people who browse questions with the Perl tag. Perl works the same way as JavaScript, PHP, C#, C++, and SQL, except for the added facility of indexing from the end of the string with negative numbers. Ruby treats strings as objects, and the notation for a substring is `str[start,length]`. In fact I can only think of Python which bucks the trend and uses `str[start:end]` instead. Are you perhaps a Python programmer?

Comment: I agree it is not a proper comment to make here. Yes I'm am mostly programming in c++, python and java - in which case the substr works in the way I am used to.

Comment: and in fact at this point I am furious at myself for not going through the documentation of substr thinking something weird is can happen and is happening since it is perl.

Comment: @sudeepdino008: Ah Java; I forgot about that one. But C++ is with the rest of us—`string std::string::substr(size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos)`